# Thymeleaf - image disappears in reply email

Tags: java, thymeleaf

When I send an email, I put an image at the end of the email (a signature).
The image is well displayed in the email.
But when the person replies to the email, the image disappears, and the ALT message has replaced the image.
Is it normal?

Below, the code :

```
<span th:if="${signatureLogo} != null">
     <img th:src="${signatureLogo}" alt="logo"/>
</span>
```

Comment: Have you tried to manually create such an email in your regular email client and have the person reply as well? Does it make a difference? I don't think this is a Thymeleaf problem.

Comment: yes, the signature is automatically attached in all my emails , and I don't have the problem when I get replies to my emails.

Comment: If you compare the email raw sources between the 2 emails, are they identical? Is `signatureLogo` a URL that is publicly accessible (from the recipients email client)?

Comment: it seems that sometimes the emails are detected as "dangerous" emails and the signatureLogo is not loaded. I don't understand why the same email is sometimes detected as dangerous, sometimes not. Doesn't seem related to thymeleaf in the end.